# Predictive or Error Tests for Vector Autoregressive Models (VAR)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, accuracy, vector-autoregression

I have two questions relating to VAR and would kindly appreciate any assistance/opinion:

Question 1:

I am having difficulty finding a proper predictive ability test for my VAR model to conclude if my model is strong & with high predictive ability.

There seems to be a variety of tests to be able to perform to assist in a generation of a Vector Autoregressive Model (VAR) i.e Granger Causality, Stationary, Number of Lags etc. But are there any tests for predictive ability/error?

I am looking for something that's like an equivalent of a MSE or R Square. Are they any accuracy tests for a completed VAR model?

Question 2:

Relating to Question 1,

Is it bias/wrong to estimate/judge/conclude the predictive ability of a VAR model by looking at Adjusted R Square/MSE results of each individual regression?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: MSE and $R^2$ are not tests but measures. Are you interested in a measure or a test?

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry for the confusion, yes I would like a measure on the predictive ability of my VAR model. Thank You.